# Preserve decimal value of new line character when parsing xml to DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, decimal, newline

I have a `xml` containing decimal value of new line eg `"&#+10;"`. 
When I parse the `xml` to `Dom`, the character is parsed as `\n`. 
Is there anyway to keep decimal representation of new line?

Comment: Please post a sample of your xml and your effort (so far) in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job of a parser is to parse: that is, to understand lexical constructs and present the application with the underlying values. `&#10;` means newline, so the parser presents the application with a newline. I don't know of any parsers that enable you to override this behaviour. But of course, there are workarounds, like preprocessing the file to replace every `&` with `§`.